# Autohotkey - How to create a variable from text in EDIT control

Tags: controls, edit, autohotkey

I want to create variables with contents of an EDIT control as shown by the following -

```
ResizeCL := "width=1920, height=1080"

Gui, Add, Edit, x26 y397 w910 h20 r1 vResizeCL, % ResizeCL
Gui, Show, w960 h465, name
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

If you run it you can see the EDIT control contents. I'm pretty sure Loop, parse might work but I didn't get very far.

Answer (score 0):

look at [StrSplit](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm), requires [AHK_L](http://ahkscript.org/)

```
ResizeCL := "width=1920, height=1080"
Gui, Add, Edit, w300 r1 vResizeCL, % ResizeCL
Gui, Add, Button, gSubmit Default, Submit
Gui, Show, , name
return

Submit:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
If InStr(ResizeCL, ",")
    for k, val in StrSplit(ResizeCL, ",", " ")
        v := StrSplit(val, "=", " ").1 , %v% := StrSplit(val, "=", " ").2
else    
    v := StrSplit(ResizeCL, "=", " ").1 , %v% := StrSplit(ResizeCL, "=", " ").2
ListVars  ; test line to view current defined variables
return
```